# How can I broadcast simple data (ticks) to other listening android apps?

Tags: android, message-passing

I have written 2 android apps.  One is a keyboard, the other is a typing speed measurer.

I would like to broadcast a "tick" to any other apps that are listening (or to nobody at all, if none are listening), whenever a key in the keyboard app is released.  I don't want this broadcast to launch the other app (if it is not running), but if it is awake and in the foreground, I want the second app to be able to count these ticks to determine how many keys have been pressed in the first app (independent of their text output).

I thought broadcasting an Intent would be a good way to accomplish this, but it appears that that will launch the second app.

A SharedPreference would also work, but that doesn't seem like the correct tool for the job.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasting an intent will not launch the second app. I think you're confusing it with `Context.startActivity()`.


Use `Context.sendBraodcast()`: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: is there then a standard way to make the name of that broadcast action queryable, so that other apps (not necessarily mine) could listen for it if they choose?

Comment: @Brent The other apps need to use intent filters with their `BroadcastReceiver`: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html